# how to print the last record of SQL server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am having a database name "fees" where i am having 4 columns (admno, receiptnumber, name, tutionfee). Here primary key is "receiptnumber". I have entered several records with different admission number. There is also several entries with same admission number. Now i just want to print only last record which i have entered. How can i print. I have written a code but first record is printing.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        string str;  
str = "select * from fees where admno='" + temp + "'";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            TextBox1.Text = reader["admno"].ToString();
            TextBox2.Text = reader["receiptnumber"].ToString();
            TextBox3.Text = reader["name"].ToString();
            TextBox4.Text = reader["tutionfee"].ToString();
```

Comment: Oh well, this is quite simple. Just reverse the ORDER of the query. In your case, probably `ORDER BY id DESC` (just guessing the index's name, assuming it's an Auto ID)

Comment: There is no concept of first and last within sql server(unless you defined some datetime to order your results). you have to defined what you mean by first and last.Based on your current structure, What you can get is the record with max value of `receiptnumber` for an `admno`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it. Add parameters to avoid sql injection! 
You need to order by your ID `DESC`ending and pick the fist one (`TOP1`)

```
string Command = "select TOP 1 * from fees where admno = @admno ORDER BY receiptnumber DSEC";
using (SqlConnection mConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    mConnection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Command, mConnection))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@admno", temp));
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            reader.Read();
            TextBox1.Text = reader["admno"].ToString();
            TextBox2.Text = reader["receiptnumber"].ToString();
            TextBox3.Text = reader["name"].ToString();
            TextBox4.Text = reader["tutionfee"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added a space between the TOP to 1 that you missed

Answer (score 2):

Assuming receiptnumber is an identity field, you would `select top 1 * from fees order by receiptnumber desc`

Comment: Downvote reason: not dealing with the more important issue: security hazard of sql injection.

Comment: Whatever makes you happy @Zohar. The OP asked how to get the last record - I showed a technique to do that. I'm trying to help people out (in the same way people helped me out when I was learning). As this is during my own work day I don't exactly have time to provide a comprehensive critique of their code.

Comment: It doesn't take much time to write something about it like "Never concatenate strings to create an sql statement since it's an opening for Sql inejction attacks, use parameterized queries instead"

Comment: Maybe - but when I have my own work to do it's *much* quicker to *scan* the question, see the OP wants to know how to get the latest record and type a 2 line reply providing that answer. Seems to me taking me to task because I tried to quickly help somebody out is churlish. Like I said though - whatever makes you happy.

Comment: You are not the only one that has a day job, you know... most of us do. It would surly take less time then to read and answer my comments. IMHO, either give the best answer you can, or none at all.

Comment: I'm not trying to boos you around, I'm just giving my own humble and honest opinion. you can take it or leave it, it's not my problem. I was just explaining the reason for my down vote, since I believe that down voting without providing an explanation is both annoying and useless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80271/discussion-between-amcdermott-and-zohar-peled).